# Calculate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2+\sin(x)} \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2+\sin(x)} \ dx$$

$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$z=\alpha(x)=e^{ix}$$

$$\sin(x)=\frac{z^2-1}{2zi}$$
$$2+\sin(x)=\frac{4zi+z^2-1}{2zi}$$
$$\frac{1}{2+\sin(x)}=\frac{2zi}{4zi+z^2-1}$$

$$\int_\alpha \frac{2zi}{4zi+z^2-1} \ \ \frac{1}{zi}$$

$$4zi+z^2-1=0$$
$$z_1=\frac{-4i+2\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$
$$z_2=\frac{-4i-2\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$

$$\rvert z_1 \rvert <1$$
$$\rvert z_2 \rvert >1$$

Using Residue theorem:

$$\int_\alpha \frac{2}{4zi+z^2-1}=2 \pi i \ \lim_{z\rightarrow-2i+\sqrt{3}i} \ \frac{2}{z+2i+\sqrt{3}i}=\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes your work seems to be fine!!

Comment: The mathematics is correct, but you are missing a few $dz$'s in your integrals, and writing a bit more text on what you're doing between each step would certainly be helpful!

Comment: you can always check your work by using some CAS like WolframAlpha...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, absolutely correct** but you may try alternative approach by converting $\sin\space x$ into $\tan\space (x/2)$  $$\sin(x) = \frac{2\cdot \tan(x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)}$$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

Set $u=tg\frac{x}{2}$ and $du=sec^2\frac{x}{2}*\frac{1}{2}dx \rightarrow dx=\frac{2}{1+u^2}dt$ and $sin(x)=\frac{2u}{u^2+1}$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2+\sin(x)} \ dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2+\sin(x)} \ dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(u^2+1)(\frac{2u}{u^2+1}+2)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{u^2+u+1}$$

And to solve this just complete the square and you will get something in  function of $arctg(u)$

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that one should shift the interval of integration to $(-\pi,\pi)$ before doing the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2+\sin(x)} dx&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+\sin^2(x/2)+\cos^2(x/2)+2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)} dx\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+(\sin(x/2)+\cos(x/2))^2} dx\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+2\sin^2(x/2+\pi/4)} dx\\
\end{align}

From here you should be able to continue recalling the behaviour of $\arctan$.